# BASH while loop with grep quiet

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep

This is a list of jobs in autosys. What I have to do is make sure that every job in PROD has a accompanying job in BACKUP. 
the jobs are formatted as **CAPSER_JOB_01_PP**. I read the list into a while loop, not sure if I should take an ***"-r"***
I take off the last two characters off of the job name, and then grep twice for each area, if both are successful it prints a yes at beginning of line, otherwise it is a no. 
 Frankly I can't find matching documentation for the **${job%??}**. I don't know what the two question marks stand for. 
I tried using **grep -q** but it did now work. the **> 2>&1 /dev/null** did not work, I had to reverse it to **> /dev/null** the the redirect **2>&1** (as shown)  The script works, it is just a clunky way of getting it done. there has to be a better way.

```
#!/bin/bash
#bash, version 3.2.25

IFS=,

while read area job machine script
do
if grep  ${job%??} /home/first_spreadsheet.txt | grep BACKUP >/dev/null 2>&1 && grep  ${job%??} /home/first_spreadsheet.txt | grep PROD  >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
echo " YES $area $job $machine $script "
else
echo " NO $area $job $machine $script "
fi
sleep 1
done < /home/first_spreadsheet.txt


cat /home/first_spreadsheet.txt
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_01_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_01_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_02_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_02_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_03_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script03'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_03_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script03'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_04_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script04'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_04_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script04'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_05_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script05'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_06_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script06'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_07_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_07_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
```

Comment: What's the question here? If it works and you're just trying to improve it, you could consider the [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: id there a better way to figure out tht a job exists in two places besides a double grep ?

Comment: Why are you putting a GNU copyright notice in your script?

Comment: I'll go to code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid the loop. You can start with

```
sort -k3 /home/first_spreadsheet.txt | uniq -c
```

or with

```
grep PROD /home/first_spreadsheet.txt | 
   grep -vf <(sed -rn '/^BACKUP/ s/^[^,]*,[^,]*,//p' /home/first_spreadsheet.txt)
```

or with

```
awk -F, '{a[$3","$4]+=1}
         END {for (key in a)
                {print key ": " a[key] " time(s)"}
             }
        ' /home/first_spreadsheet.txt
```